Passing IQueryable from controller to service and receiving back concrete list
I have a controller with a GET endpoint that can receive a number of query parameters that are used to filter entries from a database, and then the endpoint returns a list of entries that have passed the filter.
In our current implementation, the controller does everything, generating an IQueryable against a cache of the table, adding filters based on what query parameters have been provided, and then enumerates it as a list in the return statement:
[HttpGet]
public async List<MyEntity> QueryEntities([FromQuery] string[] entityName, [FromQuery] string[] entityTag, [FromQuery] string[] entityAttribute)
{
    IQueryable<MyEntity> queryParams = _cache.AsQueryable();

    if (entityName.Length > 0)  
    {
        queryParams = queryParams.Where(x => entityName.Contains(x.entityName); 
    }

    if (entityTag.Length > 0) 
    {
        queryParams = queryParams.Where(x => entityTag.Contains(x.entityTag); 
    }

    if (entityAttribute.Length > 0) 
    {
        queryParams = queryParams.Where(x => entityAttribute.Contains(x.entityAttribute); 
    }

    return await queryParams.ToListAsync();
}

As part of a feature implementation, I'm trying to move the logic and database interactions to a service class. This has largely done well but this particular method has been troublesome.
My current attempt has the service providing to the controller an IQueryable<MyEntity> on the cache, the controller adding its filters, and then in the return converting the IQueryable to a list.
If I do this with ToListAsync, I get an error:

The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations

If I make it synchronous (CodingYourLife's answer in Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations), then it works.
[HttpGet]
public async List<MyEntity> QueryEntities([FromQuery] string[] entityName, [FromQuery] string[] entityTag, [FromQuery] string[] entityAttribute)
{
    IQueryable<MyEntity> queryParams = await _myEntityDataService.GetCacheQueryable();

    if (entityName.Length > 0) 
    {
        queryParams = queryParams.Where(x => entityName.Contains(x.entityName);  
    }

    if (entityTag.Length > 0) 
    {
        queryParams = queryParams.Where(x => entityTag.Contains(x.entityTag);  
    }

    if (entityAttribute.Length > 0) 
    {
        queryParams = queryParams.Where(x => entityAttribute.Contains(x.entityAttribute); 
    }

    return queryParams.ToList();
}

I'd prefer to keep the asynchronous behavior. Is there another way to implement this that allows passing the query filters while maintain asynchronicity?
In reference to that linked question: both the controller and the service class have using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;. The accepted answer does not help in this situation.
As a more general question: it makes sense to me that the logic for handling the the query params lives in the controller itself, rather than pushing that down to lower levels. However, it also makes sense that the actual database interactions occur within a service class. I'm curious on other's thoughts on whether I have the division of responsibilities right, and if not I would appreciate seeing other proposals.

You'll need to describe what your cache is, and how your new service creates the IQueryable so we can tell why it doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable.

Chaching IQueryable has no sense, it just keep Expression Tree. If you cache data and converted IEnumerable to IQueryable, well, it is your choice, but better return IEnumerable from caching service.

Short answer is no, the IQueryable implementation by default will not work with async operations a service that interchanges between a cached list and EF IQueryable. Synchronous works just fine. You can work around it with a library like MockQueryable (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Core/7.0.2) to wrap the cached list.
This is normally used for enabling unit tests to stub out data in List<TEntity> for mocked repositories or DbSets to return in place of EF IQueryable, but it will work for any materialized lists you want to wrap with IQueryable.
If your cache is doing something like "check cache, if not loaded, load all into cache (async), return all" then your cache really benefits nothing from returning IQueryable, it can just return IEnumerable and code calling the cache can just run synchronous with the results from the cache. If it can alternate between sending entities from the DbSet<T> vs. a cache then the cached List can be wrapped with .BuildMock() to get a suitable IAsyncQueryable wrapper.
Note: when caching entities that you might use as references, i.e. attaching to a DbContext instance to be persisted with other data being inserted/updated I recommend having the caching provider clone instances of cached objects before returning them, especially if the cache is shared. (I.e. Singleton) You also want to assert that the current DbContext instance isn't tracking any such instance before attaching, opting for a tracking cache instance over a attaching a cached instance. (which would result in an instance already tracked exception)

Thank you! Your third paragraph is an accurate description of how this cache operates. I'll go ahead and make the switch to using IEnumerable.

On a side note, If you want to consider an entity caching solution for things like lookup tables I have uploaded a preliminary port of my caching library which I am tidying up for an EF guide I'm working on. (https://github.com/StevePy/Ag.Isle.EF.Core) Under the EF.Core project there is EntityCache and a marker base class/interface LookupEntity. I'm still updating documentation and unit tests around it. There is also a Scoped version that integrates with Zejji DbContextScope UoW pattern.
